# Website Scraping: Can't find the correct URL that brings me the data I want when I use the Network tab in Chrome Devtools

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, google-chrome-devtools, python-requests-html

I'm trying to scrape a radio station website to get the current charts (https://www.energy.de/programm/energy-euro-hot-30 and then https://music.apple.com/de/playlist/energy-euro-hot-30/pl.9b672a18307c4cd7ba1ece0106891868). I am using Python and the Requests HTML module. When I analyze the HTML code provided by the request, the elements I can analyze are not included. However, if I examine the page displayed in the browser, I find the desired data. I had a similar problem at the beginning of the week, when a user (https://stackoverflow.com/users/10035985/andrej-kesely) helped me.
He used Chrome Devtools and its Network tab to find the correct link to access the desired data. I have now tried this myself for my current problem, but am totally overwhelmed by the flood of connections. Maybe someone can please nudge me in the right direction...

I've tried using Chrome Devtools and their Network tab to find the correct link to get the data I need. I was not successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't see anything in Network Tab because the data is stored inside `<script>` element in the page. Here is an example how you can parse it:

```py
import json

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def find_tracks(o):
    if isinstance(o, dict):
        if o.get("itemKind") == "trackLockup":
            yield o["items"]
            return
        for v in o.values():
            yield from find_tracks(v)
    elif isinstance(o, list):
        for v in o:
            yield from find_tracks(v)


url = "https://music.apple.com/de/playlist/energy-euro-hot-30/pl.9b672a18307c4cd7ba1ece0106891868"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
data = json.loads(soup.select_one("#serialized-server-data").text)

tracks = next(find_tracks(data))

# print(json.dumps(tracks, indent=4))

for track in tracks:
    print(f'{track["title"]:<55} {track["artistName"]}')
```

Prints:

```
Overdrive (feat. Norma Jean Martine)                    Ofenbach
Houdini                                                 Dua Lipa
Strangers                                               Kenya Grace
When We Were Young (The Logical Song)                   David Guetta & Kim Petras
greedy                                                  Tate McRae
Gimme Love                                              Sia
Lose Control                                            Teddy Swims
Cynical                                                 twocolors, Safri Duo & Chris de Sarandy
Lovin On Me                                             Jack Harlow
Si No Estás                                             Iñigo Quintero
Paint The Town Red                                      Doja Cat
Water                                                   Tyla
On My Love                                              Zara Larsson & David Guetta
Is It Love                                              Loreen
I'll Be There                                           Robin Schulz, Rita Ora & Tiago PZK
Dreaming                                                Marshmello, P!nk & Sting
American Town                                           Ed Sheeran
Is It Over Now? (Taylor's Version) [From The Vault]     Taylor Swift
Better Me                                               Michael Schulte & R3HAB
Mwaki                                                   ZERB
Substitution (feat. Julian Perretta)                    Purple Disco Machine & Kungs
RUNAWAY                                                 OneRepublic
Blindside                                               James Arthur
Dive                                                    Lost Frequencies & Tom Gregory
Tattoo                                                  Loreen
LOVE'n'TENDRESSE                                        Eddy de Pretto
Prada                                                   cassö, RAYE & D-Block Europe
Never Give Up                                           Puggy
Used To Be Young                                        Miley Cyrus
Seasons                                                 Thirty Seconds to Mars
```

Comment: That worked. I have adapted your code for requests HTML. I would never have thought of the "find_tracks" function in this way. Very elegant! How did you see that the code you were looking for is retrieved by Javascript? Is that experience or is there also help from the Chrome devtools?

Comment: @ChaosKlaus I pressed `Ctrl + U` in Firefox to show source code and searched for track names.